# I have a series of python modules I would like to put into a package, how can I do this?

Tags: python, module, package

I have a series of python modules I would like to put into a package. I would like to set it up such that anyone interested can just download it and install it (on unix). How can I do this?

Comment: Step 1: Search SO for "[python] and package".  Step 2: Read the Python tutorial on packages.  Step 3: Add a file `__init__.py`.

Comment: To make one of those steps even easier, here is the [relevant section](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) from the Python tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, I already have this structure as I've seen this documentation already. I guess what I am having trouble with is putting it into an installer for anybody (say you) to download and install. Any suggestions? This may actually be more of a unix questions than a Python question...

Answer (score 1):

You should use distutils/setuptools to create egg and PyPI to distribute your package.

See according tutorials on packaging and uploading to PyPI:

http://diveintopython3.org/packaging.html

http://wiki.python.org/moin/CheeseShopTutorial